# Android KSOAP2 SoapObject

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I using `android-ksoap2` library to make `SOAP` request.

This is my code,

```
SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, SOAP_METHOD_NAME);
```

But if I don't have `NAMESPACE` in my service, just `SOAP_METHOD_NAME` can I do like this,

```
SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(SOAP_METHOD_NAME);
```

or is there another way to initialize the `SoapObject`?

Comment: have you tried passing null?

Comment: @nuser did it work with `null`?